# How to translate a property of and array of objects using vue-i18n

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I am using Nuxt 3.6.5 at this moment. I want to translate a property inside an array of objects, that are the header of a v-data-table (vuetify component), without relying on using a slot to extract the header text and translate it on the template. Here is my current code:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n"

const { t } = useI18n()

const headers = ref([
  {
    title: t('Request number'),
    align: 'start',
    sortable: true,
    key: 'numeroPedido',
  },
  ...otherObjects
])
</script>
```

Turns out that the header prop doesn't re-render and don't translate the header.

I've searched on the documentation and still, I couldn't found anything that fix this issue. I've tried use a shallowRef() on my `const headers` and the problem persists. There something that I can do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must translate the text at the moment you are going to print it on the screen. There are several ways to do this but the most comfortable from my point of view is to make the `$t` variable global in this way:

```
const i18n = createI18n({
    ... // Other options
    globalInjection: true, // Insert this line
})
```

Once injected globally you can use it inside your `<template></template>` tags without needing to import it. This way you could do something similar to this:

```
<template>
  <h1 v-for="header in headers" :key="header.key">{{ $t(header.title) }}</h1>
</template>
```

Once you have this clear you can use a custom header for your data tables, according to the Vuetify documentation you can do it with the following code:

```
<v-data-table
   :headers="headers"
   ... // Other options>
   <template v-slot:header="{ props: { headers } }">
       <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header.key">{{ $t(header.title) }}
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I hope you found it useful.